# Как отобразить заряд беспроводной мыши в Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, archlinux

У меня Arch Linux (6.8.1-arch1-1)

Мышка logitech g pro x super wireless superlight, подлючение по 2.4 ГГц

при использовании расширения UPower Battery не отображается заряд мыши, при подлючении мыши по проводу, все отображается, как сделать так, чтобы заряд мыши отображался при подключении 2.4 ГГц